# How to print the prices node.tpl.php?

Tags: commerce

I installed the [Commerce Price Savings Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_savings_formatter) module. Can you explain me how to display the price in a file `node--scs.tpl.php`? it is for a newsletter.

When I put

```
 <? php print render($content[ 'product: commerce_price']); ?>
```

It displays the full price with the original price, percent discount and the reduced price.

I want to display each item in the "td" separate.
I tried

```
<? php print render($content['product: commerce_price: Trade-price-savings-formatter-savings']); ?>
```

But it does not work.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Calling `render($content[...]);` renders the field—but you need to change *how* the field is being rendered. To do this, you'll need to modify it's display widget.

Go to Admin→Store→Configuration→Product types→*Product type*→Manage Display. Then, on the price field, change the the formatter (the first arrow):

[image: Field formatter listing from the Product type display management screen]

This can be further configured by clicking on the gear icon (right arrow) to get access to more configuration.

If this still does not suffice, try these:

1. Add a `HOOK_commerce_price_savings_formatter_formatter` to your theme to override the theme provided by the module.
2. Create a new formatter (the price saving formatter modules can be used as an example) and then use that formatter to display your prices.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, but I'm not expert :) I want to create a newletters with "simplenews" and "simplenews SCS" So I create my template with the inline style.
Here are my files: template.php http://pastebin.com/Qxaz6QHZ simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php http://pastebin.com/5uv2rH1B
node - scs.tpl.php http://pastebin.com/SkrCsMsW

see line 31 of node - scs.tpl.php

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_savings_formatter now displays the price and promotion on a line, I am able to display separately by adding two additional td line 31. A first td with the original price, a dexième td with the calculated price and a third td with the discount percentage to be customized each cell.